# What does SUMMARY DESCRIPTION command perform in Oracle SLECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, column-alias

I have a SELECT query that fetches some data from table but there is one line I can't understand at all . Can anyone tell me what does SUMMARY DESCRIPTION doing in my query cause I have no idea . Please Help .

```
     SELECT alarms.ALARMID,
      IDENTIFIER EVENT_ID,
      SERIAL ALARMID,
      NODE HOSTNAME,
      '',
      monitoredbys.OFP,
      monitored_bys.MONITORED_BY,
      productareas.PRODUCT_AREA PLATFORM,
      product_areas.PRODUCT_AREA,
      PRODUCT,
      SUMMARY DESCRIPTION


      FROM blah blah tables;
```

Can anyone tell me what does SUMMARY performs here cause I can't find any document regarding this function in ORACLE . Please Help .

Answer (score 4):

It selects the column `salary` from one of the tables and gives it the [column alias](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Creating-Simple-Queries.html#GUID-DB044D5C-A960-4813-84DA-A1880C913339) `description`. Alternatively it could be written as

```
summary AS description
```